# using linq to find if a text field contains any string in a list

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, contains, any

im running this in asp.net core v3.1

my question is similar to this question: 
[How to use Linq to check if a list of strings contains any string in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764317/how-to-use-linq-to-check-if-a-list-of-strings-contains-any-string-in-a-list)

with the specific question relating to the first answer such that

```
filterTags = ["abc", "cd", "efg"]
var results = db.People
                .Where(p => filterTags.Any(tag => p.Tags.Contains(tag)));
```

so basically saying 
give me results from the db of all People  
who's Tags field contains any of the filterTags  
where Tags = a big text field populated by a bunch of space-delimited tags

This seems straightforward (esp since this has been written before) 
but i get an error back

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(p => __filterTags_0
> .Any(tag => p.Tags.Contains(tag)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

does anyone know what this means or what im doing wrong?

Comment: did you check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667675/linq-where-list-contains-any-in-list

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI - intersect is used for two lists while im specifically looking for anything in one list to show up somewhere in a long string

Comment: I m refering to the next one , you should var People= _db.People.Where(p => p.Tagse.Split(',').ToList().Any(x => filterTags.Contains(x));

Comment: Do this code : `List<string> filterTags = new List<string> { "abc", "cd", "efg" };
            var results = db.People.ToList().Where(p => filterTags.Any(tag => p.Tags.Contains(tag))).ToList()`

Comment: Yinqiu: your solution would transfer all thousands of People from the Database to your local process before throwing away most of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with pure EF LINQ. You have to create helper which transforms your search list in Expression Tree.

```cs
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    private static MethodInfo _containsMethodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains")!;

    public static IQueryable<T> FilterUsingContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, string>> prop, IList<string> items)
    {
        if (items.Count == 0)
            return query.Where(e => 1 == 2);

        var param = prop.Parameters[0];

        var predicate = items.Select(i =>
                (Expression)Expression.Call(prop.Body, _containsMethodInfo, Expression.Constant(i, typeof(string))))
            .Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicate, param);

        return query.Where(lambda);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this extension in your queries

```cs
filterTags = ["abc", "cd", "efg"]
var results = db.People
    .Where(p => p.Tags.AsQueryable().FilterUsingContains(t => t, filterTags).Any());
```

Comment: Great! 

Just a little correction in _constainsMethodInfo (.Net Core 5.0):

`private static MethodInfo containsMethod = 
    typeof (string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[]{typeof (string)});`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a workaround for you:

```
using System.Linq; 

string[] filterTags = {"abc", "cd", "efg"};
var results = db.People.Where(p => filterTags.Contains(p.Tags)).ToList();
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile. `p.Tags` is clearly a `List<string>`. You're treating it like it is a `string`.

Comment: @Enigmativity You made a mistake. Just take a precise look at the question. It says "Tags = a big text field populated by a bunch of space-delimited tags", so Tags is a string.

Comment: There's no overload of `IEnumerable<string>.Contains` that takes a lambda. You code still does not compile.

Comment: @Enigmativity Again I should say that you don't read the question exactly. The question has mentioned that the use of Linq must be considered in the workaround. So using Linq the string array can apply the Contains method.

Comment: Perhaps you should test your code - the `IEnumerable<string>.Contains` method does not have an overload that takes a lambda. Your code would not compile.

Comment: @Enigmativity here is the compilation:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fjhnhe

Comment: The code in your answer contains a lambda. The code in your fiddle does not. `filterTags.Contains(tag => p.Tags)` versus `filterTags.Contains(tags)`.

Comment: At least it now compiles. The question now is, do you think a "a big text field populated by a bunch of space-delimited tags" will ever match ***any one of the tags*** in `filterTags`. Let's assume that `Tags` is `"abc cd efg"` then your code does ***NOT*** match.